# Override the container

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I'm working on a child theme. In the parent theme the container width doesn't starch on the whole width (the whole screen), but I want in my site only the title to be 100% width.
It doesn't work because the h1-h6 are inside the container div.
So how do I make only the headings to be 100% width although it inside the parent's container?

Comment: you need to override the container.

Comment: Please, provide more information(HTML, CSS, jsfiddle and etc). [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you explain what "the container width doesn't starch on the whole width" means.

Answer (score 0):

Yep sorry i'll explain better.
My site is based on bootstrap. bootstrap have a default container width values (

```
(@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {width: 1170px;}
```

)

Now i'm working on a child theme of a parent theme that based on bootstrap. I want **only** the title of a specific pages (product pages) to be 100% width, but I can't manage it because it inside a container. 
Solutions: 
1) Taking it outside the container. It's not possible because the container div is located in /content.php in the parent theme folder, now I'm working on a different file (single-product.php, which located in the child theme).
2)Use "position:absolute". but it mess the page and it make it none-responsive.

I tried

```
.container .product-title{
width:100%
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the index of the title class then apply the width.

```
.product-title{
z-index: 10;
width: 100%;
}
```

I hope this works for you.

(Try to edit your question instead of posting the clarification as an answer)

Comment: hey is there any other possible solution? I can't manage to solve this

Comment: To let the page fill the whole screen, change .container to .container-fluid, see [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_case_container.asp). You can also show the code at  jsfiddle  so hopefully we can help you better.